# How to return the Id of the database and not a Default Id in VUE?

Tags: database, vue.js, object, methods, key

Hello I got the following method :

```
 getAllEvents() {
      var requestOptions = {
        method: "GET",
        redirect: "follow",
      };

      let snapshot= fetch("http://localhost:8080/event/getAllData", requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(result))
          const events = []
          Object.keys(snapshot.data).forEach((key) => {
          let appData = snapshot.data[key]
        appData.id = key
        events.push(appData)
            });
            this.events = events;
        
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
    },
```

When I call it , It gets all of the event in my Database and show me in my FrontPage. My problem is that the Id of the events is not the same with the Id that my FrontPage is showing. Any idea whats the problem? I also with the specific Code I get the following

error TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting response from the result in your code:

```
Object.keys(result.data).forEach((key) => {
      let appData = snapshot.data[key]
```

Not sure if you're receiving an object in the response.data there, or an array. If it's actually an array you can use array mapping like this:

```
.then((result) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(result))
    const events = []

    this.events = response.data.map(r => {
        return {
            id: r.id  // or maybe r.key in your case
            // rest of the properties you want to map
        }
    })
})
```

Just make sure to map your properties correctly, I assumed that you have a property ID, it could be a KEY in your case.

Comment: nope same issue